# Spectrum of the Fourier Transform operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-transform

I am asked to find the spectrum of the Fourier transform operator $\mathcal F:L^2(\mathbb R)\to L^2(\mathbb R)$, where $\mathcal Fu(\omega)=\int_\mathbb R \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}u(x)e^{-ix\omega} dx$. I know that $\mathcal F^4=\mathrm{Id}$, and I read this thread already [Two questions in spectral theory: the spectrum of the Fourier transform and the Hamiltonian of the hydrogen atom.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876914/two-questions-in-spectral-theory-the-spectrum-of-the-fourier-transform-and-the). I'm lost in the last passage, how do I show that there is no residual spectrum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because $\mathcal{F}^4=I$, it follows that
$$
         (\mathcal{F}-zI)^{-1}=\frac{1}{1-z^4}(\mathcal{F}^3+z\mathcal{F}^2+z^2\mathcal{F}+z^3I),\;\;\;\; z \notin \{1,i,-1,-i\}.
$$
The operator on the right is bounded on $L^2$. So the spectrum $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ satisfies $\sigma(\mathcal{F})\subseteq\{1,i,-1,-i\}$. Conversely, every point of $\{ 1,i,-1,-i\}$ is in the point spectrum; for example, $i$ is in the point spectrum because
\begin{align}
    (\mathcal{F}-iI)(\mathcal{F}+I)(\mathcal{F}+iI)(\mathcal{F}-I)=0,\\
           (\mathcal{F}+I)(\mathcal{F}+iI)(\mathcal{F}-I) \ne 0.
\end{align}
All spectrum of $\mathcal{F}$ is, therefore, point spectrum. There is no residual or continuous spectrum. This is generally true of any bounded operator with an annihilating polynomial.